# Angular 13 request backend java interface, cross-domain error

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

Angular requested backend Spring boot Application to generate Excel's interface, and a cross-domain error occurred. But I've already done cross-domain processing on the back end, so what's going on?

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/myTicketDownload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/ticket/myTicketDownload")
    public void myTicketDownload(HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        String day = DateUtils.localDateformat(LocalDate.now());
        String fileName = URLEncoder.encode("myTicket"+day, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename*=utf-8''" + fileName + ".xlsx");
        TicketQueryDto ticketQueryDto = new TicketQueryDto();
        ticketQueryDto.setPkMyTicket("111");
        List<TicketVo> allTicketData = iTicketGeneralService.getMyTicketData(ticketQueryDto);
        EasyExcel.write(response.getOutputStream(), TicketVo.class).sheet(day).doWrite(allTicketData);

    }

//Angular 
ExportMyTicket(){
    return this.http.get<void>(`http://localhost:8080/api/ticket/myTicketDownload`)
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of error messages.

Comment: What if you set the header manually like you did with `Content-disposition`: 
`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");`

Answer (score 0):

You can't configurate CORS on the client side. Adding headers doesn't change anything. You need to configurate it in the backend. There must be somewhere a collection of domains the backend accepts.